# R Shiny + plotly : change color of a trace with javascript without affecting markers and legend in multiple plots

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

This is a follow up question based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071612/change-color-of-markers-of-a-trace-in-plotly-with-plotly-proxy-without-changing/55075235?noredirect=1#comment96898269_55075235) post.

The demo app here is a closer representation of my more complex situation of my real `shiny app` that I'm trying to improve by replacing code that causes re-`rendering` of `plotly` objects by `javascript` codes that alter the existing `plots`.

This app has:
- 4 plots with unique `ID's`
- sets of 2 `plots` listen to the same set of `colourInputs`, 1 for each `trace` in each `plot`
- the `legend` and `marker` `size` in all `plots` are linked to `numericInputs`

The modification of the `javascript` from the previous question for this solution would need to:
- follow the `size inputs`
- follow the `trace` - `colourInput` linking
- target trace `n` in 2 `plots` based on `colourInput` `n` belonging to those 2 `plots`.

**EDIT: slightly simplified scenario**
Lets drop the legend issue for now, since the solution part 2 by Stephane does what I want for the colors. I'll deal with the legend sizing later.

The modified version might be a little clearer. 
The `javascript` should:
if plot id is "`plot1`" or "`plot2`" listen to `color-set1-1` till `-3`
if plot id is '`plot3`' or '`plot4`', lister to `color-set2-1` till `-3`

I suppose we need some to add some lines in the `js` like: "

```
"var setnr = parseInt(id.split('-')[1]) ;",
```

to see which set of buttons we are looking at, followed by an if statement that achieves:

```
 if 'setnr'  == set1 , then var plots =  plot1, plot2
    else if 'setnr == set2, then var plots = plot3, plot4
and then update the trace in 'plots'
```

In the new app, the color-set1-1, color-set1-2, color-set1-3 still target all 4 plots.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- c(
  "function(el,x){",
  "  $('[id^=Color]').on('change', function(){",
  "    var color = this.value;",
  "    var id = this.id;",
  "    var index = parseInt(id.split('-')[1]) - 1;",
  "    var data = el.data;",
  "    var marker = data[index].marker;",
  "    marker.color = color;",
  "    Plotly.restyle(el, {marker: marker}, [index]);",
  "  });",
  "}")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot1")),
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot2")),
    column(4,
    colourInput("Color-1", "Color item 1", value = "blue"),  # these buttons will become named Color-set1-1, Color-set1-2, Color-set1-3
    colourInput("Color-2", "Color item 2", value = "red"),  # but that requires an extra change to the js
    colourInput("Color-3", "Color item 3", value = "green")
  )
    ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot3")),
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot4")),
    column(4,
           colourInput("Color-set2-1", "Color item 1", value = "blue"),
           colourInput("Color-set2-2", "Color item 2", value = "red"),
           colourInput("Color-set2-3", "Color item 3", value = "green")
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(colors1 = c('red', 'blue', 'black'), colors2 = c('yellow', 'blue', 'green')  )

  myplotly <- function(THEPLOT, xvar, setnr) {
    markersize <- input[[paste('markersize', THEPLOT, sep = '_')]] 
    markerlegendsize <- input[[paste('legendsize', THEPLOT, sep = '_')]]
    colors <- isolate ({values[[paste('colors', setnr, sep = '')]]  })
    p <- plot_ly(source = paste('plotlyplot', THEPLOT, sep = '.'))
    p <-  add_trace(p, data = mtcars, x = mtcars[[xvar]], y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~as.factor(cyl), colors = colors)
    p <- layout(p, title = 'mtcars group by cyl with switching colors')
    p <- plotly_build(p) 
    p  %>% onRender(js)
    } 

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot1', 'hp', 1) })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot2', 'disp', 1)})
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot3','hp', 2)})
  output$plot4 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot4', 'disp', 2)})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**The original APP:**

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(colourpicker)
library(shinyjs)

## javascript from previous question's answer:
jsCode <- "shinyjs.changelegend = function(){
var paths = d3.select('#plot1').
select('.legend').
select('.scrollbox').
selectAll('.traces').
select('.scatterpts')
.attr('d','M8,0A8,8 0 1,1 0,-8A8,8 0 0,1 8,0Z');}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"),
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  fluidRow(
    column(2,numericInput(inputId = 'markersize_plot1', label = 'marker', min = 1, max = 40, value = 20)),
    column(2,numericInput(inputId = 'legendsize_plot1', label = 'legend', min = 1, max = 40, value = 10)),
    column(2,numericInput(inputId = 'markersize_plot2', label = 'marker', min = 1, max = 40, value = 4)),
    column(2,numericInput(inputId = 'legendsize_plot2', label = 'legend', min = 1, max = 40, value = 20))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot1")),
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot2")),
    column(2,uiOutput('buttons_color_1'))
  ),
fluidRow(
  column(2,numericInput(inputId = 'markersize_plot3', label = 'marker', min = 1, max = 40, value = 10)),
  column(2,numericInput(inputId = 'legendsize_plot3', label = 'legend', min = 1, max = 40, value = 30)),
  column(2,numericInput(inputId = 'markersize_plot4', label = 'marker', min = 1, max = 40, value = 7)),
  column(2,numericInput(inputId = 'legendsize_plot4', label = 'legend', min = 1, max = 40, value = 40))
),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot3")),
    column(4,plotlyOutput("plot4")),
    column(2,uiOutput('buttons_color_2'))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(colors1 = c('red', 'blue', 'black'), colors2 = c('yellow', 'blue', 'green')  )


  lapply(c(1:2), function(i) {
  output[[paste('buttons_color_', i,sep = '')]] <- renderUI({
    isolate({ lapply(1:3, function(x) {  ## 3 in my app changes based on clustering output of my model
      Idname <- if(i == 1) { COLElement_1(x) } else {COLElement_2(x) }
      div(colourpicker::colourInput(inputId = Idname, label = NULL,
                                    palette = "limited", allowedCols = TheColors,
                                    value = values[[paste('colors', i, sep = '')]][x],
                                    showColour = "background", returnName = TRUE),
          style = " height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align:center; padding: 0px; display:block; margin: 10px")
    })
    })})

  outputOptions(output, paste('buttons_color_', i,sep = ''), suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  })


  COLElement_1 <-    function(idx){sprintf("COL_button_1-%d",idx)}
  lapply(1:3, function(ob) { 
  COLElement_1 <- COLElement_1(ob)
  observeEvent(input[[COLElement_1]], {
    values[[paste('colors', 1, sep = '')]][ob] <- input[[COLElement_1]]
    plotlyProxy("plot1", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", list(marker = list(color = input[[COLElement_1]])), list(as.numeric(ob)-1))
    plotlyProxy("plot2", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", list(marker = list(color = input[[COLElement_1]])), list(as.numeric(ob)-1))
  })  
  })

  COLElement_2 <-    function(idx){sprintf("COL_button_2-%d",idx)}
  lapply(1:3, function(ob) { 

  COLElement_2 <- COLElement_2(ob)
  observeEvent(input[[COLElement_2]], {
    values[[paste('colors', 2, sep = '')]][ob] <- input[[COLElement_2]]
    plotlyProxy("plot3", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", list(marker = list(color = input[[COLElement_2]])), list(as.numeric(ob)-1))
    plotlyProxy("plot4", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", list(marker = list(color = input[[COLElement_2]])), list(as.numeric(ob)-1))
  })
  })

  myplotly <- function(THEPLOT, xvar, setnr) {
    markersize <- input[[paste('markersize', THEPLOT, sep = '_')]] 
    markerlegendsize <- input[[paste('legendsize', THEPLOT, sep = '_')]]
    colors <- isolate ({values[[paste('colors', setnr, sep = '')]]  })
    p <- plot_ly(source = paste('plotlyplot', THEPLOT, sep = '.'))
    p <-  add_trace(p, data = mtcars, x = mtcars[[xvar]], y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = ~as.factor(cyl), colors = colors)
    p <- layout(p, title = 'mtcars group by cyl with switching colors')
    p <- plotly_build(p) 


    # this is a bit of a hack to change the size of the legend markers to not be equal to the plot marker size.
    # it makes a list of 1 size value for each marker in de trace in the plot, and another half of with sizes that are a lot bigger.
    # the legend marker size is effectively the average size of all markers of a trace
    for(i in seq(1, length(sort(unique(mtcars$cyl) )))) {
      length.group <- nrow(mtcars[which(mtcars$cyl  == sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[i]), ])
      p$x$data[[i]]$marker$size <- c(rep(markersize,length.group), rep(c(-markersize+2*markerlegendsize), length.group))
    }
    p
  } 



output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot1', 'hp', 1) })
output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot2', 'disp', 1)})
output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot3','hp', 2)})
output$plot4 <- renderPlotly({ myplotly('plot4', 'disp', 2)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is the "legend size" ? And I don't understand why you supply a vector in `p$x$data[[i]]$marker$size`. The marker is a single number, no?

Comment: yeah it's a bit odd, it's a hack I found long long ago. basically what it does is, if there are for instance 107 points in a trace, is to supply 107 equal sizes for the markers, followed by 107 bigger sizes to boost the legend markers which behave as an average of all sizes in the p$x$data[[i]]$marker$size of the plotly object. This because plotly still hasn't provided us with a legend(markersize = x) argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm lost :)
Let's start. Here is an app allowing to change the marker size:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

js <- paste(c(
  "$(document).ready(function(){",
  "  $('#size').on('change', function(){",
  "    var size = Number(this.value);",
  "    var plot = document.getElementById('plot');",
  "    var data = plot.data;",
  "    $.each(data, function(index,value){",
  "      var marker = data[index].marker;",
  "      marker.size = size;",
  "      Plotly.restyle(plot, {marker: marker}, [index]);",
  "    });",
  "  });",
  "})"), sep = "\n")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  numericInput("size", "Size", value = 5, min = 1, max = 15)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly()
    for(name in c("drat", "wt", "qsec"))
    {
      p <- add_markers(p, x = as.numeric(mtcars$cyl), y = as.numeric(mtcars[[name]]), name = name)
    }
    p 
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is an app allowing to change the marker color:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- c(
  "function(el,x){",
  "  $('[id^=Color]').on('change', function(){",
  "    var color = this.value;",
  "    var id = this.id;",
  "    var index = parseInt(id.split('-')[1]) - 1;",
  "    var data = el.data;",
  "    var marker = data[index].marker;",
  "    marker.color = color;",
  "    Plotly.restyle(el, {marker: marker}, [index]);",
  "  });",
  "}")

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  colourInput("Color-1", "Color item 1", value = "blue"),
  colourInput("Color-2", "Color item 2", value = "red"),
  colourInput("Color-3", "Color item 3", value = "green")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly()
    for(name in c("drat", "wt", "qsec"))
    {
      p <- add_markers(p, x = as.numeric(mtcars$cyl), y = as.numeric(mtcars[[name]]), name = name)
    }
    p %>% onRender(js)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does it help?

Comment: I love how fast the color app updates the trace! I added a modifief, simpler app focussing on only the colors, and how to make colorInput set1 focus on the top 2 plots, and colorInput set2 on the bottom 2 plots.

Comment: I wrote a new question for better scenario and some attempts by me to make it work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102492/r-shiny-plotly-update-trace-colors-with-javascript-when-colourinput-is-build-in

Answer (score -1):

With shiny, you can use `color=~get(input$XXX)`. Here's an example with my own code:

```r
fig = plot_mapbox()
# POLYGONS
fig = fig %>% add_sf(
  data=districts,
  split=~DISTRICT,
  color=~log10(get(input$multi_indicator_districts.selectors.colorBy)))
# POINTS
fig = fig %>% add_trace(
  type='scatter',
  data=facilities,
  x=~longitude,
  y=~latitude,
  split=~tier)
fig = fig %>% layout(
  mapbox=list(
    zoom=4,
    style='open-street-map'))
```

[image]